# Foundation Toggle-able Sidebar with Icons Like Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I am trying to build a sidebar navigation like the one used in the Wordpress admin dashboard. I like the option to collapse the sidebar but still see the icons. I'm using Zurb Foundation and jQuery. I finally have a solution that I think might work, but it's doing some funny things. The `<li>`s are all different widths, until I collapse and reopen the menu for the first time. Then they all stay the same size. So here are my questions:

1. How can I make the `li`s be the same size on the first load?
2. How can I make the main content resize and push over when the sidebar opens (instead of getting pushed down, which is what is currently happening)?
3. I want the sidebar to appear open on the first page load (with icons and titles), but then if the user toggles it closed (to just the icon view), it should stay closed as they navigate the site. How do I do that?

[Here's a jsFiddle with my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/regularmegs/2vweLpnf/1/)

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas on how to get this to work with the jsFiddle I posted? I couldn't get the answer below to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a tutorial to do this, and works like a charm, you only need to adapt it to Foundation [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/)

In your particular case, since you want to have teh icons always visible, just open components.css and replace

```
.gn-menu-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 60px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 60px;
border-top: 1px solid #C6D0DA;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
transform: translateX(-60px);
transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s, width 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

with

```
.gn-menu-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 60px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 60px;
border-top: 1px solid #C6D0DA;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
transform: translateX(-60px);
transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s, width 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the icons to stay but the titles to toggle. That tutorial has the whole sidebar toggling.

Comment: see edit, was just editing while you posted your comment

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. It looks complicated though. If anyone has a solution for the code I posted or a Foundation-ready solution, I'd appreciate it.